# I can't get <p:dataTable> working for me

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am not sure why I am able to show my data using `<h:dataTabel><h:column></h:column></h:dataTable>` but not with `<p:tableTable>`.  I have imported  primefaces-5.2-source.jar under WEB-INF->lib and also imported primefaces-5.2.jar as external jar file. 
here is my code for XHTML file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>         
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p ="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f ="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h ="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
 <f:metadata>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{processFilesController.loadRecords()}"/>
</f:metadata>

    <h:head>
      <title>Records</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

            <h1>List of processed data with at least one matching word</h1>
            <h:form id="currentRecordForm">
                <p:dataTable id="currentRecordDataTable" value="#{processFilesController.records}" var="currentRecord">

                    <p:column id="mainId" headerText="id1">
                        <h:outputText value="#{currentRecord.id1}"></h:outputText>
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

processFileController code

```
@ManagedBean

public class ProcessFilesController {

    private DataModel<Record> records;
    private ProcessFilesUtility processFilesUtility;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName(),null);

    public ProcessFilesController(){
        processFilesUtility = new ProcessFilesUtility();
    }

    public DataModel<Record> getRecords() {
        loadRecords();
        return records;
    }

    public void loadRecords() {
        records = processFilesUtility.getProcessedData();
    }
}
```

I would like to use some of the nice property of primefaces library to do pagination. That is why I am using primefaces.

If I use the very same code but instead of `<p:dataTable>` I use `<h:dataTable>` and instead of `<p:column>` I use `<h:column>` I will get my data showing on the page. I am curious why it does not work with xlmns:p ??

Comment: Your example works for me except of your duplicate namespace declaration `xmlns:h ="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"`. What IDE are you using? Be sure to clean caches or work directories before redeploying.

Comment: @thunderhook, Thank you for answering my question. I am using Eclipse - I just cleaned the project. But it still does not work for me and does not show any data on the screen.

Comment: @thunderhook I am passing a dataModelArray to my xhtml file. Can it be the reason?

Comment: Maybe, please post your code of `processFilesController`.

Comment: Hey are you getting some error ? can you you put your java code as well.

Comment: sure I will put my processFileController

Comment: To exclude the most obvious cause, a primefaces.jar IS deployed in the app on the **server**?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes I have a tomcat server running and I ran the app on this server. One thing came to my mind is that maybe primefaces only handle a specific type of data type being passed to them. Maybe they can't read ArrayDataModel